# How to get a list of all users who reacted in discord.py rewrite

Tags: discord.py

I have searched for an answer to this question, but the only answer I had found was from around a year ago. This is what I have:

```
@client.command()
async def arena(ctx):
  rembed = discord.Embed(
    title = 'React to join an arena event',
    color = discord.Color.red()
  )
  knife = ''
  message = await ctx.send(embed=rembed)
  await message.add_reaction(knife)
  await asyncio.sleep(3)
  for reaction in message.reactions:
    for user in reaction.users():
      await ctx.send(f"users: {user.name}")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the discord.py docs, they recommend doing something like this:

```py
users = await reaction.users().flatten()
# users is now a list of User...
winner = random.choice(users)
await channel.send('{} has won the raffle.'.format(winner))
```

Therefore, in your case, this is what you may want to do.

```py
@client.command()
async def react_test(ctx):
    rembed = discord.Embed(
        title = 'React to join an arena event',
        color = discord.Color.red()
    )
    knife = ''
    message = await ctx.send(embed=rembed)
    await message.add_reaction(knife)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    getmsg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(message.id)
    users = await getmsg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
    for user in users:
        await ctx.send(user.name)
```

Result of above code:

[image: Who uses only reaction.users().flatten() anyway]

---

Refrences:

- [Reaction - Discord.py Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#reaction)